# JWT token not being validated correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that uses JWT for validation

I add the authentication in the startup class, using our token secret in our appsettings file to validate the token.

```
services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);

services.AddAuthentication(x => {
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x => {
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew =  TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

And add the authorization middleware

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Now when a user tries to login the following controller method is run, using the same token secret to generate the token.

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userForLoginDto.Username);

        var result = await _signInManager
            .CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, userForLoginDto.Password, false);



        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                    .GetBytes(appSettings.Token)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return Ok(new { token });
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

So when the user logs in, a token is generated and send back to the client.

At this point I would expect that I could just add `[Authorize]` attribute to a controller method, and then the MVC framework will look for a valid token in the http headers. So I create a test controller method

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("Test");
}
```

And send a request that corresponds to the test controller method with the Authorization header set to `Bearer <Token>` yet I still get a 401 unauthorized.

Can anyone explain why this might happen? Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: Is the token you're sending valid (check in https://jwt.io/) ?

Comment: @auburg Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the matter of using your middleware:

```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Could try it in the following way:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
```

So first, we use authenticate the user - where the middleware reads the token and inject the identity to http context

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Comment: glad, I could help :)